# Merge request: [android-honeycomb] and [honeycomb]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

A question posted a minute ago caused me to notice that Stack Overflow has both a [android-honeycomb](/questions/tagged/android-honeycomb) tag and a [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb) tag. I think they should be merged and one should be made a synonym of the other. <strike>On top of that, my opinion is that both should be made synonyms for [android-3.0](/questions/tagged/android-3.0), so that all questions will simply fall under that tag. Having all three seems kind of silly.</strike>

Edit: Disregard the latter part, I forgot 3.1 is out now and is also codenamed "Honeycomb." Making `honeycomb` always point to `android-3.0` probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: Android 3.1 is also codenamed "Honeycomb".

Comment: @Al: True, I forgot 3.1 is out now. Actually, that kind of makes me feel like `[honeycomb]` could turn into a somewhat confusing tag in the near future, since there are some changes to the SDK platform between 3.0 and 3.1...