# Honeycomb Tag Synonym Request

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Could you add [android-3.0](/questions/tagged/android-3.0) as synonym of [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb) (since it's used quite often already at stackoverflow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't think this is a good idea. The issue (sort of) came up with [a merge request I posted previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/merge-request-android-honeycomb-and-honeycomb), but [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb) is, in my opinion, actually *not a good tag* anymore. There are currently 3 versions of Android which are referred to as "Honeycomb": 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2. There was also a similar request, [but in the opposite direction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93076/propose-android-honeycomb-is-synonym-of-android-3-0-tag).

The problem I see is that the 3 Honeycomb versions actually use 3 different API revisions. As an example, some USB APIs were added in API level 12 which were not available in 3.0, so tagging [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb) on a question regarding USB interfacing could result in answers which are totally useless if you're targeting API level 11 (3.0 devices). I think it's actually important to at least keep the version specific tags around, though I also think they should be encouraged over the more vague [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb).

Comment: I partially agree - but in fact the version-specific tags are hardly used, 3.1 and 3.2 is not yet present at all